# I need to remove serial number from string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to remove (1.) serial number from the string(1. this is text)
How i remove the serial number from string and get the given output.

```
var str = '1. This is dummy text(1.1).';


Output:

This is dummy text(1.1).
```

Comment: You just want to remove 1. or do you want to make it generic, ie. remove every first number followed by a dot?

Comment: Provide your efforts what you have tried ?

Comment: `str.replace(/^\d+\./m, '')`

Answer (score 5):

You can use replace with regex

```
str.replace(/^\d+\.\s+/, '')
```

this will replace:

```
^ // from the beginning of the string
\d+ // one or multiple digits
\. // followed by literal dot
\s+ // followed by one or multiple whitespace characters
```